# Can't do: git clone

Tags: git, github, clone, logentries

Im triyng to clone the repository project into my desktop git hub window and it failed
I got these errors inside the log file:

**Log File Errors**

```
2016-07-20 09:04:11.4932|INFO|thread:14|DashboardViewModel|Selected repository 'techla/webroshhayin'
2016-07-20 09:04:11.5922|INFO|thread:14|DashboardViewModel|Took 0ms to Create RepositoryViewModel for location D:\Documents\GitHub\webroshhayin
2016-07-20 09:04:12.1092|ERROR|thread:16|ComparisonGraph|JavaScript Alert from the comparison graph: http://github-app/: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectCommit' of null
2016-07-20 09:08:11.6309|INFO|thread:76|GitLfsSmudgeTail|Cleaning up Git LFS smudge progress environment variable
2016-07-20 09:08:11.6739|WARN|thread: 1|StandardUserErrors|Showing user error Please check your log file for more details, or contact out support team if you are still having problems.
```

Solution on how to resolve this issue will be appreciated

Comment: git clone  and then repository url ,

Comment: Yes I know but its not working... I have tried to do it in my desktop git hub and in the command but its not working..

Comment: check git version (latest) and try this format `git clone https://username@github.com/org/project.git`

Comment: In command wrote that the clone done, but I dont see the project folder in my local gitHub folder.

Comment: provide your repo. url, i will try

Comment: Do you have a desktop git hub program?

Comment: This is a link for what I'm trying to tell you: https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: no, which repository you want to clone.

Comment: Ok thank you your answer was working only in the shell but its very good, do you want to remove this answer from comments and make it like answer? I want to mark your answer :)

Comment: i recommend don't use third party application. use git directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check git version (latest) and try this format

```
git clone https://username@github.com/org/project.git
```